# PHP Reference to a static variable

Tags: php, class, reference, static-members, static-variables

I'm not sure if this is possible at all in PHP but this is what I try to do. I have a static variable in my class that I want to have as a reference outside the class.

```
class Foo {

  protected static $bar=123;

  function GetReference() {

    return self::&$bar; // I want to return a reference to the static member variable.
  }

  function Magic() {

    self::$bar = "Magic";
  }
}

$Inst = new Foo;
$Ref = $Inst->GetReference();
print $Ref; // Prints 123
$Inst->DoMagic();
print $Ref; // Prints 'Magic'
```

Can someone confirm if this is possible at all or another solution to achieve the same result:

- The variable must be static because class Foo is a base class and all derivates needs access to the same data.
- HTML needs access to the class reference data, but not to be able to set it without a setter method because the class needs to know when the variable is set.

I guess it can always be solved with globals declared outside the class and some coding disciplines as an emergency solution.

// Thanks

[EDIT]
Yes, I use PHP 5.3.2

Comment: What is your target PHP version?

Comment: Why make a reference?  In most cases it can be handled without a reference (for example, using explicit getters/setters).  References make code which is rather difficult to debug (since side-effects in one piece of code can effect other pieces of code).  Try to stay away from them unless **absolutely** necessary (which in my experience is seldom)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP documentation provides a solution: [Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

```
<?php
class foo {
    protected $value = 42;

    public function &getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }
}

$obj = new foo;
$myValue = &$obj->getValue(); // $myValue is a reference to $obj->value, which is 42.
$obj->value = 2;
echo $myValue;
```

Comment: if you make $value public, you can directly access that outside from the class

Comment: +1v It works!!! I'm an old fashion C++ OOP, so I kept it protected :) I was googling high and low and never came across this. Well, guess I have to improve my search technique as well :D Thank you!

Comment: ajreal that's correct. I updated the example. Now, it makes more sense.

Comment: I don't always need to lookup how to reference object variables, but when I do, i'm using PHP.